# Error during Taxonomy CSV import

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, migrations, importing-exporting

I am using the [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module to import and export taxonomy from my local installation to a fresh install on the staging. I export it on local, and import it using the same settings on staging. However, for each entry it imports, it throws an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: format in
>   _taxonomy_csv_vocabulary_import_process() (line 421 of /var/www/vhosts/example.com/drupal-7.34/sites/all/modules/taxonomy_csv/import/taxonomy_csv.import.api.inc).

However, the import is successful. Does anyone else encounter this? Is is safe to ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notice is a known issue. You can solve it by implementing one of these patches:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1535942
or
https://www.drupal.org/node/2196065

If you do not know how to apply a patch, follow these instructions:
https://www.drupal.org/patch/apply